# Prevent Laravel Accessor involved when do query just for some column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've made accessor for formatting date on my table model,
and this is my model looks like for the accessor

```
class Agent  Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    protected $appends = ['created_at_formatted'];

    ...

     public function getCreatedAtformattedAttribute()
     {
         return $this->created_at->format('d-m-Y');
     }
   ...
}
```

there is no problem with that if I retrieve all data from the table,

but the problem comes if I only take some data, for example, I take only `phone` and `email` for specific User, and the `created_at` column not involved,

and, my query on controller looks like this:

```
    public function getAgentDetail($id)
    {
        $agDetail = Agent::where('id','=' ,50)->get(['phone','email']);
        return response()->json($agDetail);
    }
```

and the query above gives me an error :

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError`

`Call to a member function format() on null`

and I think it's because no value was given to the accessor (in this case `created_at`),
so I change the accessor on my model to this:

```
    public function getCreatedAtformattedAttribute()
    {
         $this->created_at
                ? $this->created_at->format('d-m-Y')
                : null;
    }
```

it only gives a condition if it is not set, it will return a null value,
The error disappears and returns this collection :

```
[
  {
    phone: "086741111111",
    email: "example@jab.com",
    created_at_formatted: null
  }
]
```

What I want is, how to ignore accessor involved when only select specify column, which has nothing to do with the accessor,

for example, I just want to get the `phone` and `email`, and not for `created_at_formatted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line and try again:

```
protected $appends = ['created_at_formatted'];
```

Acessors can be called without appending them. Also you may want to change the function name to `getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute` to respect Laravel's convention.